# Java code beautifier not giving last characters

Tags: java

I tried with this code to creates a code beautifier. But if it finds a `"}"`, beautify is breaking. How can I fix it with this code?

```
String code = "class Demo{public static void main(String[] args) {System.out.println(\"ABC\");if(\"A\".equals(\"A\")){return \"A\";}System.out.println(\"ABC\");}}";
String outtext = code;
String repfrom = "{";
String repto = "{\n";


Pattern p = Pattern.compile(repfrom, Pattern.LITERAL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(outtext);

int counter = 0;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    counter++;
    m.appendReplacement(sb, repto + (tab += "\t"));
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String newtext = sb.toString().replace(";", ";\n" + tab);
String replace = "";
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    replace = newtext.replace("}", "\b}");
}


System.out.println(replace);
```

My output is:

```
class Demo{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("ABC");
        if("A".equals("A")){
        return "A";
    }System.out.println("ABC");
    }
```

Comment: @progenhard The last closing brace is missing from the output.

Comment: You can't concatenate `\b` to delete the previous character.

Comment: I coded something like this once. I looped through the whole thing 1 character at a time and inserted newlines and tabs where necessary

Comment: maybe `newtext.replace(tab+"}", "}");` ?

Comment: @bentaye I rolled back your edit, you shouldn't change importantent contents of the question. The output under the question was the result of his script, and the question was about the missing } inside that output. By changing the output, you just removed the issue the OP is showing to us.

Comment: @Ferrybig Ho you're right, sorry about that, I'll read the question better next time. I'm glad you picked it up.